# How to properly check if a UIImage is nil using the YouTube Api v3 in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, youtube-api

I'm having an issue checking if a `UIImage` is nil in order to display a `UIAlertViewController`.

My app fetches playlists from a youtube channel. One of the playlist contains a video that has been removed by YouTube, and therefore does not contain a "thumbnails" key when fetching the playlist data.

This is the code I've implemented to check whether there is a thumbnail image to display, otherwise display an Alert.

```
print("playlistVideos_ARRAY = \(self.playlistVideos_ARRAY)")

print("startOfNextIndexForVideos = \(self.startOfNextIndexForVideos)")

if let thumbnailImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: ( ( ( (self.playlistVideos_ARRAY[self.startOfNextIndexForVideos] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["snippet"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["thumbnails"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["high"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> )["url"] as! String )! )! )!
{
     print("111111111")
     self.thumbnailOfVideo.append(thumbnailImage)
}
else
{
     print("222222222")

     let message = UIAlertController(title: "Uh Oh!", message: "There is an issue with this playlist :(", preferredStyle: .Alert)

     let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                        message.addAction(defaultAction)

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            self.presentViewController(message, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        })
}
```

However, it never outputs `222222222`. It always fails right at the if check with the following output:

```
playlistVideos_ARRAY = [{
    etag = "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/Jl892aZsvFYpvjE5ENwTItH9cqQ\"";
    id = PLP2q8Ric9B9X6r8L2LA7xRwg0HNnKL3RLaooSkbmjTxo;
    kind = "youtube#playlistItem";
    snippet =     {
        channelId = UC5ltMmeC4YFaart1SSXdmAg;
        channelTitle = "Viet My Television";
        description = "This video is private.";
        playlistId = "PLxnnlv22Xcq34TNdsMxEIKvIHE_phd7XK";
        position = 0;
        publishedAt = "2016-03-16T18:51:39.000Z";
        resourceId =         {
            kind = "youtube#video";
            videoId = uPnWMZ1pbSc;
        };
        title = "Private video";
    };
}]
startOfNextIndexForVideos = 0
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What am I doing wrong in terms of checking this? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here's an output of my `playlistVideos_ARRAY` fetched via a GET request that contains a valid playlist with a thumbnail of the associated video that hasn't been removed by YouTube:

```
playlistVideos_ARRAY = [{
    etag = "\"q5k97EMVGxODeKcDgp8gnMu79wM/U4OVbnjwS2bbU44Q1Hijy6-koAE\"";
    id = "PLP2q8Ric9B9VZXfc41HzRjprfOHpOYQd_SbLAuuxZVyw";
    kind = "youtube#playlistItem";
    snippet =     {
        channelId = UC5ltMmeC4YFaart1SSXdmAg;
        channelTitle = "Viet My Television";
        description = "";
        playlistId = PLxnnlv22Xcq0HpE242iwHh8IP78esU9sF;
        position = 0;
        publishedAt = "2016-02-15T23:25:20.000Z";
        resourceId =         {
            kind = "youtube#video";
            videoId = mIW5trLZJcM;
        };
        thumbnails =         {
            default =             {
                height = 90;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mIW5trLZJcM/default.jpg";
                width = 120;
            };
            high =             {
                height = 360;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mIW5trLZJcM/hqdefault.jpg";
                width = 480;
            };
            medium =             {
                height = 180;
                url = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mIW5trLZJcM/mqdefault.jpg";
                width = 320;
            };
        };
        title = "talkshow chuong trinh hoi cho tet Binh Than o Miles Square Park";
    };
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, optional chaining is preferred when you do not know whether a dictionary key exists. This will prevent crashes due to attempts to force unwrap optionals with nil values.

If your data object was a nested Dictionary of all Swift types it would be as simple as:

```
if let url = playListVideos_ARRAY[startOfNextIndexForVideos]["snippet"]?["thumbnails"]?["high"]?["url"] {
    // attempt to create the image using the successfully obtained url here
}
```

To handle your case, I'd try breaking up the `if let` statement into comma separated list, replace all your `as!` with `as?`, and only attempt to create the image if the url key was found:

```
if let dict = playListVideos_ARRAY[startOfNextIndexForVideos] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>,
    snippet = dict["snippet"] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>,
    thumbnails = snippet["thumbnails"] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>,
    high = thumbnails["high"] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>,
    url = high["url"] as? Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> {
        // create your image with the url here
    } else {
        // do your thing with "2222222.."
    }
```

Comment: I've already implemented a solution, but I just tried yours and it worked out the same, so I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 0):

is it something like this

```
if([yourarray valueForKey:@"thumbnails"]!=nil){
        NSLog("Key is found.");
    }
    else{
        NSLog("key is not found..playlist not available");
    }
```